# Cannot insert data into SQL Server from Windows form

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a window form that displays a Calendar Event.

And when I add an event on specific date, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'value'

at the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

This is my code:

```
namespace PRN_Project
{
    public partial class EventForm : Form
    {
        String ConnectionString = "server=DESKTOP-7NUQVBN; database=Calendar; uid=sa; pwd=123";

        public EventForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EventForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbDate.Text = UserControlDays.static_day + "/" + CalendarForm.static_month + "/" + CalendarForm.static_year;
        }

        private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO CalendarEvent (TimeDate, EventName) VALUE (?, ?)";

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeDate", tbDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventName", tbEvent.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Saved!");

            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using SQL Server authentication.

The datatype for `TimeDate` and `EventName` is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: **VALUES** not **VALUE**. [`INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2)`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: `VALUES` not `VALUE`. And you should ideally use named parameters `INSERT INTO CalendarEvent(TimeDate, EventName) values (@TimeDate, EventName)`. Also note: [`AddWithValue` is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), specify parameter types and lengths explicitly. And you need `using` blocks on the connection and command objects

Comment: @Charlieface
can you explain specific for me please, i m new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this one:**

```
private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            String sql = "INSERT INTO CalendarEvent(TimeDate, EventName)values(@TimeDate,@EventName)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDate", tbDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", tbEvent.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved !!!");
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

and you can use TRY Catch Finally

```
private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                String sql = "INSERT INTO CalendarEvent(TimeDate, EventName)values(@TimeDate,@EventName)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDate", tbDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", tbEvent.Text);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved !!!");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
                
                
                
    }
```

Comment: Instead of the try..catch--finally, just use `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) { ... }`

Comment: @Klaus Gütter  thanks. and your way is another good way and good idea.